# Why GCP instance required to allow port 80 manually even if default port (BranchCache Content Retrieval (HTTP-In)) 80 is open in windows firewall

Tags: tomcat, deployment, google-cloud-platform, firewall

I've set up the new GCP instance, while initial setup I reserve static IP for my instance to access my application using IP address or URL, but when I install the tomcat on windows and update the port (from 8080 to 80) in the connector, I couldn't access my tomcat outside.

I have checked the windows firewall rules there is one default rule(BranchCache Content Retrieval (HTTP-In)) for port 80 and that is open in inbound and outbound, still I can't access tomcat. Then I create one rule manually for port 80 and enabled it. That works for me.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: There should be some configuration in the default (BranchCache Content Retrieval (HTTP-In)) that was preventing the ingress from an external source. You can describe it by typing ' Get-BCStatus ' or ' netsh branchcache show status all ' there you will be able to identify whats wrong with the default one.

Answer (score 1):

Because the Windows firewall and network security group are at different locations in the network.

If you block a port at any location, that port is blocked. You must enable that port in each location.

A Google Cloud VPC knows nothing about the firewall running inside your VM. For example, if you enable port 80 in a security group, but disable port 80 in the Windows firewall, port 80 traffic will be blocked. Network traffic must pass thru the security group before arriving at the VM.

Comment: Thank you John for your reply, but that port is already enabled with the default firewall group created by VM (BranchCache Content Retrieval (HTTP-In).

Comment: Your question was: "Why GCP instance required to allow port 80 ..."